# Dividing the value of 2 textfields in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have my view controller hooked up with my swift file within my Xcode project. I have 2 text fields (One to type in number of games played and another to type in number of points scored). When someone taps the calculate button I want the code to divide the number of games by the number of points scored and display the point per game average on a label. I have provided a screenshot of the view controller below.

[image]

Comment: FWIW this is Andy's school project....it was mentioned in the question...which I deleted it to keep the question pure...but I thought others might want to know due to the cuteness of the question :D

Comment: If this is homework you should have an attempt yourself first and then post the code that you are having a problem with along with the error message. You will learn a lot more if you work through this yourself and do not treat Stack Overflow as a code writing service. To get you started: `1)` Hook your `UITextField`s and your `UILabel` up to your `UIViewController` using `IBOutlet`s. `2)` Write a function that uses `guard let` statements to validate the inputs are real numbers and that `Games Played` is not `0` `3)` Calculate the average points per game and set the text of the output `UILabel`

Comment: @RoboticCat as a young newbie you get a free pass 1-2 times...any question after that then you're right...he should show his code.

Comment: Andy...usually for total beginners I recommend to see youtube. Just search for "how to update label using textfield swift" or "uitextfield label swift" in youtube. For example see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEGFADjp_q0)...There are like 100 youtube channels dedicated to Swift and iOS just search and you'll see

Answer (score 1):

So the biggest thing that you are going to run into is the fact that you are trying to convert String? to a Double so you really need to validate all of your data. I would go something along the following route.

```
func clickButton(sender:UIButton){
   guard let pointsText = numberOfPoints.text, !pointsText.isEmpty else {
       // alert that the text field is empty
       return
   }
   guard let gamesText = numberOfGames, !gamesText.isEmpty else {
       // alert that the text field is empty
       return
   }
   guard let points = Double(pointsText), points >= 0 else {
       // alert that you can't have negative points or that the entered text did not convert to a number
       return
   }
   guard let games = Double(pointsText), games > 0 else {
       // alert that you can't have negative or zero games or that the entered text did not convert to a number
       return
   }
   let pointAverage = points/games
   outputlabel.text = "\(pointAverage)"
}
```

You always have to be careful with optional values because if they are nil and you try to force unwrap them the app will crash. Likewise when converting from String to a number you can run into issues as they are returned as optionals as well since "ABC" will not convert to a number, but "123" will.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply connect your textfield in viewcontroller to your class and calculate points like this. This is just an example for clickButton function.

```
func clickButton(sender:UIButton){
       let point = Int(numberofgames.text)/Int(numberofpoint.text)
       outputlabel.text = String(point)

}
```